# Issue with updating new row by using the mongodb driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb

How can I add a new row with the update operation

I am using following code

```
statuscollection.update({
    id: record.id
  }, {
    id: record.id,
    ip: value
  }, {
    upsert: true
  }, function (err, result) {
    console.log(err);
    if (!err) {

      return context.sendJson([], 404);
    }
  });
```

While calling this first one i will add the row
  id: record.id

Then `id:value` then i have to add `id:ggh`

How can i add every new row by calling this function for each document I need to insert

Answer (score 1):

By the structure of your code you are probably missing a few concepts.

1. You are using [update](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) in a case where you probably do not need to.
2. You seem to be providing an `id` field when the primary key for MongoDB would be `_id`. If that is what you mean.

If you are intending to add a new document on every call then you probably should be using [insert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/). Your use of [update](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) with [upsert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-parameter) has an intended usage of matching a document with the query criteria, if the document exists update the fields as specified, if not then insert a new document with the fields specified.

Unless that actually is your goal then [insert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/) is most certainly what you need. In that case you are likely to rely on the value of `_id` being populated automatically or by supplying your own unique value yourself. Unless you specifically want another field as an identifier that is not unique then you will likely want to be using the `_id` field as described before.